# How to attach source code as dependency in java

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, multi-project

I have two projects in java. **ProjectA** is published into artifactory, and **projectAB** has **jar** of **projectA** as a dependency.

When I make changes in projectA, in order to completely test it, I need to run tests in projectAB (these tests can not be moved into projectA).

What I want is to make changes in projectA, and instantly run tests in projectAB.

Naive schema: change projectA, publish projectA, test projectAB looks too complex.

Idealy for me, I'd like to set in my IDE to override projectA.jar dependency with project A, so I can threat projectA and projectAB as the single project. But I havent found a way to do it.

I use IDEA as IDE and Gradle as a build system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider using [Gradle composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) or [Gradle multi-projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) that were made exactly for this purpose.